# overloading a function which differs from the original only by "const" in parameter list

Tags: c++, constants, overloading

I have a question about overloading a function with only difference in "const". For instance, if there is a function A, which is pass-by-reference, it is ok to overload it by pass-by-reference-to-const. However, when will the first one being invoked, and when will the second one being invoked?
Thanks!

Comment: From my tests, a temporary will never bind to the non-`const` version. And the non-temporary will always bind to the non- `const` version if they are not `const`. Look at [this](http://ideone.com/DF64I8)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's definitely OK.

```
void foo(int& ) { std::cout << "ref\n"; }
void foo(const int& ) { std::cout << "cref\n"; }
```

The first one will be invoked if you pass a non-const lvalue of type `int`. The second one will be invoked in any other case.

```
int i = 4;
const int ci = i;

foo(4);  // cref
foo(i);  //  ref
foo(ci); // cref
foo(1L); // cref

struct X {
    operator int() { return 42; }
};

foo(X{}); // cref
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I thought pass-by-reference-to-const only constraints the function from modifying the reference. But from the example, it also constraints on the caller?? It is great to know!

Answer (score 0):

I assume you mean something like

```
void A(int& arg)
{
    ...
}

void A(const int& arg)
{
    ...
}
```

Then you can use the function like

```
int i = 5;
A(i);  // will call `A(int&)`
A(5);  // will call `A(const int&)`

const int ci = 5;
A(ci);  // will call `A(const int&)`
```